# SQLAlchemy Attempting to Twice Delete Many to Many Secondary Relationship

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have a `product` model with a many to many relationship to `product_categories` as described below:

```
class Product(Base):
    """ The SQLAlchemy declarative model class for a Product object. """
    __tablename__ = 'products'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    part_number = Column(String(10), nullable=False, unique=True)
    name = Column(String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = Column(String(2000), nullable=False)
    categories = relationship('Category', secondary=product_categories,
                               backref=backref('categories', lazy='dynamic'))


class Category(Base):
    """ The SQLAlchemy declarative model class for a Category object. """                        
    __tablename__ = 'categories'                                                                 

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    lft = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    rgt = Column(Integer, nullable=False)                                                        
    name = Column(String(80), nullable=False)                                                    
    description = Column(String(2000), nullable=False)                                           
    order = Column(Integer)                                                                      
    products = relationship('Product', secondary=product_categories,
                               backref=backref('products', lazy='dynamic', order_by=name))

product_categories = Table('product_categories', Base.metadata,
    Column('products_id', Integer, ForeignKey('products.id')),
    Column('categories_id', Integer, ForeignKey('categories.id'))
)
```

Then, I'm trying to delete this object with:

```
product = DBSession.query(Product).filter_by(name = 'Algaecide').one()
DBSession().delete(product)
```

But, what I get is the error message `StaleDataError: DELETE statement on table 'product_categories' expected to delete 1 row(s); Only 0 were matched.`.  If you notice, it appears to be running the `DELETE` statement twice.  So, the first time it's successfully removes the product_id from the `product_categories` table, but then attempts to do it yet again for whatever reason, and then decides it needs to throw an exception because it's not there.

```
>>> Attempting to delete the product 'Algaecide' assigned to categories: [<myproject.models.category.Category object at 0x106fa9d90>]
21:39:50 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][Dummy-2] SELECT categories.id AS categories_id, categories.lft AS categories_lft, categories.rgt AS categories_rgt, categories.name AS categories_name, categories.description AS categories_description, categories.`order` AS categories_order
FROM categories, product_categories
WHERE %s = product_categories.products_id AND categories.id = product_categories.categories_id ORDER BY categories.name
21:39:50 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][Dummy-2] (109L,)
21:39:50 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][Dummy-2] DELETE FROM product_categories WHERE product_categories.products_id = %s AND product_categories.categories_id = %s
21:39:50 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][Dummy-2] (109L, 18L)
21:39:50 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][Dummy-2] DELETE FROM product_categories WHERE product_categories.products_id = %s AND product_categories.categories_id = %s
21:39:50 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][Dummy-2] (109L, 18L)
21:39:50 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][Dummy-2] ROLLBACK
21:39:50 ERROR [pyramid_debugtoolbar][Dummy-2] Exception at http://0.0.0.0:6543/product/Algaecide/edit
traceback url: http://0.0.0.0:6543/_debug_toolbar/exception?token=6344937a98ee26992689&tb=4421411920
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-2.3-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/toolbar.py", line 178, in toolbar_tween
    response = _handler(request)
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-2.3-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/performance.py", line 57, in resource_timer_handler
    result = handler(request)
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/tweens.py", line 21, in excview_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.10-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 95, in tm_tween
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.10-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 83, in tm_tween
    manager.commit()
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transaction-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/transaction/_manager.py", line 111, in commit
    return self.get().commit()
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transaction-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/transaction/_transaction.py", line 280, in commit
    reraise(t, v, tb)
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transaction-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/transaction/_transaction.py", line 271, in commit
    self._commitResources()
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transaction-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/transaction/_transaction.py", line 417, in _commitResources
    reraise(t, v, tb)
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transaction-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/transaction/_transaction.py", line 389, in _commitResources
    rm.tpc_begin(self)
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.sqlalchemy-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/zope/sqlalchemy/datamanager.py", line 90, in tpc_begin
    self.session.flush()
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1919, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2037, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2001, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 372, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 479, in execute
    self.dependency_processor.process_deletes(uow, states)
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/dependency.py", line 1023, in process_deletes
    secondary_update, secondary_delete)
  File "/Users/derek/pyramid/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/dependency.py", line 1111, in _run_crud
    result.rowcount)
StaleDataError: DELETE statement on table 'product_categories' expected to delete 1 row(s); Only 0 were matched.
```

Am I missing some sort of a 'gotcha' in this case?  Seems like a pretty standard implementation.  Why is it attempting to execute the `DELETE` statement twice?

Comment: I searched around on this a bit more and found several cases.  Fortunately, one had the suggestion to set the following `engine` options:
    `engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')`
    `engine.dialect.supports_sane_rowcount = engine.dialect.supports_sane_multi_rowcount = False`

This seems to have worked, thankfully!
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/ajYLEuhEB9k

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a bit more searching, I found the following link which suggests it's a MySQL bug:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/ajYLEuhEB9k

Thankfully, disabling `supports_san_multi_rowcount` helped!

```
engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
engine.dialect.supports_sane_rowcount = engine.dialect.supports_sane_multi_rowcount = False
```

Good enough for me for now.  Here's another interesting resources I found along the way dealing with postgresql:
https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3015/deletes-executed-twice-when-using